What is the main role of cross-domain transformer encoder in htdemucs?
Now I am studying music source separation using htdemucs. As you know, in htdemucs, we use cross-domain transformer encoder layer instead of shared encoder/decoder layer which use BLSTM in hybrid demucs. Please tell me what is the main role of cross-domain transformer encoder and the architecture of this encoder. Thanks for your help.
